# FFmpeg and Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I'm getting the error `RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available` when trying to run [this](https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter12.04-Animations-and-Movies.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20animations%20in,the%20animation%20functionality%20is%20built.) simple example of creating and displaying an animation in a *Jupyter Notebook*.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-799d6a3690af> in <module>
      8 
      9 # Define the meta data for the movie
---> 10 FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
     11 metadata = dict(title='Movie Test', artist='Matplotlib',
     12                 comment='a red circle following a blue sine wave')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in __getitem__(self, name)
    164         if self.is_available(name):
    165             return self._registered[name]
--> 166         raise RuntimeError(f"Requested MovieWriter ({name}) not available")
    167 
    168 

RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available
```

Running `!pip install ffmpeg` didn't help, as `ffmpeg` is already installed, apparently:

```
Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this, but it took me quite some time to find the right solution, so I will share it in case it helps someone. Basically, you need to download the latest static build of `FFmpeg` and add it to `PATH`, so that it can be found by `python`. You can do this easily by running [this](https://github.com/jina-jyl/jupyter/blob/77c998f89c908c14c59c01519b572828e7563ffb/util/load-ffmpeg.ipynb) script:

```
# Download a static FFmpeg build and add it to PATH.
exist = !which ffmpeg
if not exist:
  !curl https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz -o ffmpeg.tar.xz \
     && tar -xf ffmpeg.tar.xz && rm ffmpeg.tar.xz
  ffmdir = !find . -iname ffmpeg-*-static
  path = %env PATH
  path = path + ':' + ffmdir[0]
  %env PATH $path
print('')
!which ffmpeg
print('Done!')
```

Hope it helps!